# Erazor recursive helper

Tags: recursion, haxe, erazor

I post here my question because haxe mailing list is pretty busy with the haxe3 rc relase.
I would like to have some expertise from´others about how to built a recursive helper for erazor template engine used with haxe.

I have a treenode ( polygonal.ds.Treenode ) which is nested to simulate a html hierarchy.
Now i would like to export my treeNode to a string with nested divs. 
I could do it in a recursive function on the logic part of my app, but i'd  really like to be able to have it on the templating system.

Does anyone achieved to work with such a recursive helper ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it is worth asking on the list?  People might welcome a non-haxe3 related question... I don't have enough experience with Erazor (or Polygonal) to know what the best solution is.